# Bootstrap datepicker -- how to get date as a string in the right format?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker). The answer is probably obvious, but I can't figure out how to get the selected date as a string in the specified format. I used:

```
<div id="myDate" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

And in my javascript:

```
var value = $("#myDate").datepicker("getDate");
```

But it returns a date, not a string in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy"` needs to be set on the input:

```
<input type="text" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

Your jQuery should also be changed to:

```
var value = $("#myDate input").datepicker("getDate");
```

Or you can just keep things simple with no wrapping `div` and with this your original jQuery would work fine and you wouldn't have to specify `input`:

```
<input type="text" id="myDate" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD">
```

**Suggestion**
I would recommend creating a class to format the datepicker. So that you can then add the `.datepicker` class to any input field and it would work without having to specify another variable.

**Fiddle**
Here is working code with alert of date http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/HFuDg/1/

Comment: Thanks. I actually omitted some things. The wrapping div includes a <span class="add-on">

Comment: I see. Did adding the `data-date-format` to the input fix the issue, or is it still happening?

Comment: Still happening. The getDate method still returns an object. It's a different object now, and appears to be part of the DOM. (The input perhaps?)

Comment: @ccleve Here is a link that shows the results http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/HFuDg/1/ I also updated my answer

Comment: I want to collect multiple dates in my datepicker using var nbworkersdate = $('.nbworkersDate',r).datepicker("getDates") and what I get is a list of todays dates not the ones insertted. Why?

Answer (score 11):

```
var value = $("#myDate").datepicker("getFormattedDate");
```

Comment: This is an undocumented method and works perfectly. Especially when the date picker is embedded (`<div>` instead of an `<input>`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the value as a string use: var value = $("#myDate input").val();

The method getDate returns an object

Comment: version 1.9.0 does not return an object

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
$("#myDate").data('datepicker').getFormattedDate('yyyy-mm-dd');
```

you will have it in prover format even if you set a different format to display the data for users like this

```
<input id="myDate" type="text" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY">
```