# Formatting bootstrap-datepicker result

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

So here is how i setup my datepicker

```
$('#picker').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  multidate: true
});
```

and then here is how i showing the result

```
 $('#picker').on('changeDate', function(event) {
        console.log( $('#picker').datepicker("getDates"));
      });
```

here is the result from console

```
[Tue Jun 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Waktu Indonesia Barat), Wed Jun 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Waktu Indonesia Barat), Wed Jun 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Waktu Indonesia Barat)]
```

How can i make it to `yyyy-mm-dd` format ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195828/bootstrap-datepicker-how-to-get-date-as-a-string-in-the-right-format

Comment: @TonyNguyen i already did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how i fix it

```
 $('#picker').datepicker("getFormattedDate")
```

maybe it will help others

Answer (score 0):

Give [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) a try. It is a very powerful tool not just only to format Date objects, but to manipulate them and make custom validations.